# $_POST is empty while posting with file

Tags: php, file-upload, yii

I am using PHP. I am facing an issue with $_POST global array. when I send or add one record without file and enctype is removed from form tag it working correctly. but I upload a file and enctype is set to multipart/form-data $_POST variable is not set.I done so far following code to upload the file.

index.php

```
<form action="add.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="artist_name" />
<input type="text" name="title" />
<input type="file" name="track_file" />
</form>
```

add.php

```
<?php
     $artist=$_POST['artist_name'];
     $title=$_POST['title'];
     $song=$_FILES['track_file']['name'];  
     echo $artist;
     echo $song;
?>
```

Comment: Your file is probably too big.

Comment: I see that, you edited your post twice there, 1st was `$_FILES` and second was `form`, make sure you copy paste your code from the source, don't type the thing here, it creates a mess of typo answers down there.

Comment: in relation to the comment from Jack, you can try using a small file to test out

Answer (score 2):

you should also use isset function to check if your post values are set. Just to avoid notifications

Comment: i checked this they are not set

Answer (score 0):

It would be `$_FILES` not `$_FILE` like

```
$song = $_FILES['track_file']['name'];
```

Comment: @Manohar Bomma have you tried it..??

Comment: I tried but no success

Comment: @Simon_eQ I just asked is it working or not.Not to accept or vote\

Answer (score 0):

It should be `form` not `from`:

```
<*form* action="add.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="artist_name" />
<input type="text" name="title" />
<input type="file" name="track_file" />
</form>
```